# Payflow link error - token missing

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

Using the payflowlink example from their documantation and altering it for my payflow account information, I get the following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="LOGIN" value="dcmcs1">
    <input type="hidden" name="PARTNER" value="paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION" value="Invoice">
    <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="S">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Invoice">
</form>
```

However, I get this page generic response which does not say what is missing.

```
Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.

Error: Token is missing. Please return to the website from where you started your purchase and try again.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which example are you following ? [Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowlink_guide.pdf) states `However, new Payflow Link customers who are using the Secure Token or the API should not
use this guide`

Comment: I had not planned on using hte secure token, but as a new customer, they must be forcing that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new customer and if you are planning to integrate with PayflowLink. There are 2 ways 
Option - 1. By posting all parameters to Payflowlink (which is what you are trying)
Option - 2. By using secure token ( which is more secure as your information is concealed and recommended way )

The error you are facing is in your Manager settings secure token is enabled. With your account credentials go to manager.paypal.com , then go to account administration and then hosted page setup , there you will have to disable Secure token. This will allow you to launch the way you want as in Option 1